# While loop malfunction, random integrer only works first time

Tags: c#

This code is supposed to make a random number and then see if that placement is taken or available, it works fine the first time, but when its the bots second turn, it just spams Error: You've already placed on here, try again.
I am making a 3 in a row bot for school, and im stuck.

```
    static int EasyMode(int plats1, int plats2, int plats3, int plats4, int plats5, int plats6, 
    int plats7, int plats8, int plats9) {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    int random = dt.Millisecond;
    random = dt.Millisecond;
    random = (random / 100);
    bool finished = false;
    while (finished == false) {
        random = dt.Millisecond;
        random = (random / 100);
        if (random == 0) {
            random = dt.Millisecond;
            random = (random / 100);
        }
        else if (random == 10) {
            random = dt.Millisecond;
            random = (random / 100);
        }
        else {
            switch (random) {
                case 1:
                    if (plats1 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats1 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 1;
                    }
                case 2:
                    if (plats2 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats2 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 2;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if (plats3 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats3 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 3;
                    }
                case 4:
                    if (plats4 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats4 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 4;
                    }
                case 5:
                    if (plats5 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats5 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 5;
                    }
                case 6:
                    if (plats6 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats6 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 6;
                    }
                case 7:
                    if (plats7 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats7 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 7;
                    }
                case 8:
                    if (plats8 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats8 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 8;
                    }
                case 9:
                    if (plats9 == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: You've already placed on here, try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (plats9 == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: This spot is taken by the bot");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        finished = true;
                        return 9;
                    }
            }
            continue;
        }
        continue;
    }
    return 69;
}
```

( I needed more details)

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting with the debugger and seeing what the values are and why it is behaving like it is?

Comment: Where exactly the error or issue present. Have you tried debugging that?

Comment: `dt` doesnt keep updating its value. Its only set to the current date **once**. If you need the updated value, you will need to keep checking/assigning with `DateTime.Now`

Comment: @Rahul i am unsure exactly were the issue takes place, the second run the method is used it returns the same value, even though i thought i made it so it guesses over and over again until it gets a value that is not taken

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 `Millisecond` will not be precise enough to generate random number in "fast" cycle

Comment: @GuruStron I'm well aware, just pointing out the issue as it stands

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 How can i do that inside the while loop? so it updates at each start of the time loop

Comment: Why are you using the millisecond portion of the current time as a random number?  There are better random number generators, start by looking at `Random()`

Comment: @FabianLundholm  As others have said, the build in Random class is far better at generating actual random numbers, an easier to use. You also suffer from a condition we call "spagetti code" and using Random can help you remove those extra if statements. Finally, the contents of your switch cases are all really similar and you should look into extracting those into a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need random value you should use `Random` class. Like this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.Next(1, 10); // assuming 1 is minimum and 9 is maximum, 
// upper boundary is exclusive 
bool finished = false;
while (finished == false) {
    // generate value here the same way if needed
```

Comment: As i am in school, i can only use my chromebook, and therefore i have to use an online compiler, currently i am using .Net fiddle and to my knowledge it doesnt have either random class or debugging features

Answer (score 0):

Your random number is always going to be the same. The variable `dt` doesn't get updated with the value of `DateTime.Now` like you seem to expect. The value is set once (when you assign it) to the current time.

To keep your current mechanism in tact, you would need to keep querying `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` (instead of `dt`)

```
while(!finished)
{
     int random = DateTime.Now.Millisecond / 100;
     // do stuff with random value
     // if zero or ten, continue loop go get new value
     if (random == 0 || random == 10) {
         continue;
     } else {
         // etc 
     } 
}
```

But note in a loop like this, `DateTime.Millisecond` is not really the best choice. Due to its precision and the nature of this loop, many successive iterations may end up with the same value. Plus on its own its not the best random number generator.

What you should *really* do is use a framework class specifically for this purpose--`Random`--to get values between 0 and 99

```
var rand = new Random(); // outside of loop
while(!finished)
{
     var random = rand.Next(0, 100);
     // do stuff with random value
     // if zero or ten, continue loop go get new value
     if (random == 0 || random == 10) {
         continue;
     } else {
         // etc 
     } 
}
```

Also note that it appears you *really* want numbers between 0-10 (or rather, 1-9 inclusive) in which case you could use any of the following:

Using `Random` with bounds properly set:

```
int random = rand.Next(1, 10); // 1-9
```

Using `Millisecond` modulo 10:

```
int random = DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 10; // 0-9,  still need to test its not zero
```

Using `Millisecond` modulo 9:

```
int random = (DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 9) + 1; // 1-9
```